# Issue with using a TFS vNext task: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to create a simple TFS vNext task, using Powershell to execute a Powershell script.

I could load the task, but after I trigger a release using the task, I get

```
##[error]System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PoolName'.
```

My task.json is as below.

```
{
    "id": "7fe28fb2-c323-4494-beb6-b5c5939b09e7",
    "name": "ManageIIS",
    "friendlyName": "ManageIIS",
    "description": "ManageIIS",
    "helpMarkDown": "ManageIIS",
    "category": "Utility",
    "visibility": [
        "Build"
    ],
    "author": "Baskar Lingam",
    "version": {
        "Major": 1,
        "Minor": 0,
        "Patch": 3
    },
    "demands": [],
    "minimumAgentVersion": "1.83.0",
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "advanced",
            "displayName": "Advanced",
            "isExpanded": false
        }
    ],
    "instanceNameFormat": "ManageIIS",
    "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "PoolName",
      "type": "string",
      "label": "Application Pool Name",
      "required": true,
      "defaultValue": "AppPoolName"
    },
    {
      "name": "AppPoolAction",
      "type": "pickList",
      "label": "App Pool Action (Stop or Start)",
      "required": true,
      "defaultValue": "",
      "helpMarkDown": "Name of the Database",
      "options": {
        "Stop": "Stop App Pool",
        "Start": "Start App Pool"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "ResetIIS",
      "type": "boolean",
      "label": "Reset IIS",
      "defaultValue": "false",
      "required": true,
      "helpMarkDown": "To reset IIS on a web server"
    }
  ],
    "execution": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "target": "ManageIIS.ps1",
            "argumentFormat": "",
            "workingDirectory": "$(currentDirectory)"
        }
    }
}
```

And my Powershell script is here.

```
#####################################################################

# Author        : Baskar Lingam Ramachandran
# Created Date  : 25th Nov 2016
# Updated Date  : 30th Nov 2016

######################################################################

[CmdletBinding()]
Param()

Trace-VstsEnteringInvocation $MyInvocation

try
{
    # Get the inputs.
    [string]$PoolName = Get-VstsInput -Name PoolName
    [string]$AppPoolAction = Get-VstsInput -Name AppPoolAction
    [bool]$ResetIIS = Get-VstsInput -Name ResetIIS -AsBool

    # Load the require module to manage IIS
    <#if(-not(Get-Module WebAdministration))
    {
        Import-Module WebAdministration
    }
    #>

    # Code for App pool stop or start
    if (($AppPoolAction -eq "Stop") -or ($AppPoolAction -eq "Start"))
    {
        if(-not($PoolName))
            {
                Write-Host "`t`tApp pool name is not provided. Please provide the same.`r`n" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
        else
            {
                if($AppPoolAction -eq "Stop")
                {
                    if(Test-Path IIS:\AppPools\$PoolName)
                    {
                        Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName exists`r`n"
                        if(-not((Get-WebAppPoolState $PoolName).Value -eq "stopped"))
                        {

                            Write-Host "`t`t-------------------------------------------------`r`n"
                            Write-Host "`t`tStopping application pool $PoolName`r`n"
                            Write-Host "`t`t-------------------------------------------------`r`n"

                            Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName is not stopped. Stopping it now.`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
                            Stop-WebAppPool $PoolName
                            Write-Host "`t`tThe command execution is complete.`r`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                            $appPoolState = Get-WebAppPoolState $PoolName
                            Write-Host "`t`tThe current state of the app pool $PoolName is $($appPoolState.Value).`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName is already stopped.`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName does not exist`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
                    }            
                }
                if($AppPoolAction -eq "Start")
                {
                    if(Test-Path IIS:\AppPools\$PoolName)
                    {
                        Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName exists`r`n"
                        if(-not((Get-WebAppPoolState $PoolName).Value -eq "Started"))
                        {

                            Write-Host "`t`t-------------------------------------------------`r`n"
                            Write-Host "`t`tStarting application pool $PoolName`r`n"
                            Write-Host "`t`t-------------------------------------------------`r`n"

                            Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName is not started. Starting it now.`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
                            Start-WebAppPool $PoolName
                            Write-Host "`t`tThe command execution is complete.`r`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                            $appPoolState = Get-WebAppPoolState $PoolName
                            Write-Host "`t`tThe current state of the app pool $PoolName is $($appPoolState.Value).`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName is already started.`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName does not exist`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
                    }            
                }
            }
        }

    if ($ResetIIS -eq "true")
    {
        iisreset -stop -noforce
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
        {
            Write-Host "`t`tInternet services successfully stopped`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        }
        iisreset -start -noforce
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
        {
            Write-Host "`t`tInternet services successfully started`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
        }
    }

} finally {
    Trace-VstsLeavingInvocation $MyInvocation
}
```

I have another simple task which does not take any parameter and it works perfectly fine.

Any pointers?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the VSTS Build Task SDK you need to be using Powershell 3..

"execution": { "PowerShell3": { "target": "ManageIIS.ps1", } }

Answer (score 2):

From the script context Error, I can see that the error you have received presently is because powershell is unable to get the value of the '***PoolName***' in the "***Get-VstsInput***" command.

Secondly if you are passing the parameters on the fly in the script then you have to use the parameters inside the param.

I would still recommend you to use Args[0], Args[1] and so on as a method of parameter passing.
Mostly we use params in a function.

I believe you have already compiled the functions("**Trace-VstsEnteringInvocation**" and "**Get-VstsInput**") somewhere before; Other wise it would have thrown you an error as unrecognized terms.

As per your script , I have tweaked a little bit and also put comments on the scripts;
Below  is the script:

```
#####################################################################

# Author        : Baskar Lingam Ramachandran
# Created Date  : 25th Nov 2016
# Updated Date  : 30th Nov 2016

######################################################################

[CmdletBinding()]
Param($PoolName,$AppPoolAction,$ResetIIS)  # Taking the input as parameters

# I would suggest you to make the functions as Global so that you can use it anywhere freely and call from any block.
Trace-VstsEnteringInvocation $MyInvocation

try
{

    # Get the inputs.
    [string]$PoolName = Get-VstsInput -Name PoolName
    "The value of PoolName is $PoolName" # This helps in input validation, we can check it if it is returning the proper value or not.
    [string]$AppPoolAction = Get-VstsInput -Name AppPoolAction
    [bool]$ResetIIS = Get-VstsInput -Name ResetIIS -AsBool

    # Load the require module to manage IIS
    <#if(-not(Get-Module WebAdministration))
    {
        Import-Module WebAdministration
    }
    #>

    # Code for App pool stop or start
    if (($AppPoolAction -eq "Stop") -or ($AppPoolAction -eq "Start"))
    {
        if(-not($PoolName))
            {
                Write-Host "`t`tApp pool name is not provided. Please provide the same.`r`n" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
        else
            {
                if($AppPoolAction -eq "Stop")
                {
                    if(Test-Path IIS:\AppPools\$PoolName)
                    {
                        Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName exists`r`n"
                        if(-not((Get-WebAppPoolState $PoolName).Value -eq "stopped"))
                        {

                            Write-Host "`t`t-------------------------------------------------`r`n"
                            Write-Host "`t`tStopping application pool $PoolName`r`n"
                            Write-Host "`t`t-------------------------------------------------`r`n"

                            Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName is not stopped. Stopping it now.`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
                            Stop-WebAppPool $PoolName
                            Write-Host "`t`tThe command execution is complete.`r`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                            $appPoolState = Get-WebAppPoolState $PoolName
                            Write-Host "`t`tThe current state of the app pool $PoolName is $($appPoolState.Value).`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName is already stopped.`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName does not exist`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
                    }            
                }
                if($AppPoolAction -eq "Start")
                {
                    if(Test-Path IIS:\AppPools\$PoolName)
                    {
                        Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName exists`r`n"
                        if(-not((Get-WebAppPoolState $PoolName).Value -eq "Started"))
                        {

                            Write-Host "`t`t-------------------------------------------------`r`n"
                            Write-Host "`t`tStarting application pool $PoolName`r`n"
                            Write-Host "`t`t-------------------------------------------------`r`n"

                            Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName is not started. Starting it now.`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
                            Start-WebAppPool $PoolName
                            Write-Host "`t`tThe command execution is complete.`r`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                            $appPoolState = Get-WebAppPoolState $PoolName
                            Write-Host "`t`tThe current state of the app pool $PoolName is $($appPoolState.Value).`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName is already started.`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Write-Host "`t`tApp Pool $PoolName does not exist`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
                    }            
                }
            }
        }

    if ($ResetIIS -eq "true")
    {
        iisreset -stop -noforce
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
        {
            Write-Host "`t`tInternet services successfully stopped`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        }
        iisreset -start -noforce
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
        {
            Write-Host "`t`tInternet services successfully started`r`n" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
        }
    }

} finally {
    Trace-VstsLeavingInvocation $MyInvocation
}
```

Hope this answer suffice/helps you. Feel free to like it because that will help others too.

Comment: I much appreciate your answer. When I use the parameters in the param() like `param([string]$PoolName,[string]$AppPoolAction,[string]$ResetIIS)` I start to get errors for Trace-Vsts* commands and get-VSTSInput commands. I have the standard VstsTaskSdk (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/tree/master/powershell/VstsTaskSdk) kept at the folder. So I just removed the Trace-Vsts* and Get-VstsInput commands from the script and it worked well.

Comment: Great.. Its all worth if it is fulfilling the requirement...:)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question, as I have found another working way (as used in VSTS Microsoft tasks https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks) in addition to the answer from Ranadip Gupta. I have upvoted Ranadip's answer. But providing my own answer as there is yet another way as well.

1. Ranadip Gupta's answer works well after I removed Trace-VstsEnteringInvocation, Trace-VstsLeavingInvocation and Get-VstsInput commands from the PS1 script.

   You need to define the parameters in the param() itself like below, for this method to work.

   param([string]$PoolName, [string]$AppPoolAction, [string]$ResetIIS)

   To use Args[] in the PS1, be aware that the arguments passed to the PS1 are in the format

   -PoolName TFD -AppPoolAction Stop -ResetIIS true

   So you need to use $($Args[1]), $($Args[3]), $($Args[5]) to refer to the values obtained for the various parameters, as $($Args[0]),$($Args[2]),$($Args[4]) refer to the parameters themselves.
2. The second way is changing the execution of the **task.json** from **Powershell to Powershell3**. With this method I could make use of Trace-Vsts* and Get-VstsInput commands. In this method the param([string]$PoolName,[string]$AppPoolAction, [string]$ResetIIS) can be kept as param().

   from

   "execution": {
       "PowerShell": {
           "target": "ManageIIS.ps1",
       }
   }

   to

   "execution": {
       **"PowerShell3"**: {
           "target": "ManageIIS.ps1",
       }
   }